# Javascript not working in WordPress page template

Tags: wordpress

I do custom wordpress theme. I made a template for home page but JavaScript does not work for it.

I tried to alert `hello world` and it worked, but when tried to make our work filter it's not working for page template.

```
let switcherLis = document.querySelectorAll(".switcher li");
let imgs = Array.from(document.images);

switcherLis.forEach((li)=>{
    li.addEventListener("click", removeActive);
    li.addEventListener("click", manageImgs);
});

// Remove active class from all li and add it to current
function removeActive() {
    switcherLis.forEach((li)=>{
        li.classList.remove("active");
        this.classList.add("active")
    });
}

// Manage Imgs
function manageImgs() {
    imgs.forEach((img)=>{
        img.style.display = "none";
    });
    document.querySelectorAll(this.dataset.cat).forEach((el)=>{
        el.style.display = "block";
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not executing code before the dom is loaded?

Comment: I enqued script file in functions.php. I alert hello world successfully. I'm not sure but it seems since it page template there is a specefic way

Comment: You can try adding those JS codes directly from the browser console and see the result. I think this is a good way to know what's going on.